# What is the defined behavior of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() when the location changes?

Tags: android, file, io

**General Problem:**

People are complaining about data loss after app update of data that is stored on 'external storage directory'

**What I'm doing:**

I'm using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the external storage directory to store files outside the internal memory to get the chance to be able to store those on the SD card.

I'm running into the problem that after each app update a very low amount of users is complaining that the files stored in the app are not visible any more.

There is a paragraph in the official documentation of this method saying:

> This path may change between platform versions, so applications should
>   only persist relative paths.

in my app I'm getting my directory with the following code:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIRECTORY_NAME + "/");
```

Depending on the Android version this will be a different `dir`. e.g. `/mnt/sdcard/dir_name`, `/storage/sdcard0/dir_name`

In case `dir` does not exist, I create the directory. This is the same behavior that happens on a new install.

**Question:**

What happens when the OS is updated. Is there a guarantee that the old location will exist as a symlink to the new location?
How can people complain about data loss after an app update?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the external storage directory to store files outside the internal memory to get the chance to be able to store those on the SD card.

External storage on Android does not have anything necessarily to do with "the SD card". In particular, on modern devices, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is highly unlikely to be a removable medium.

> in my app I'm getting my directory with the following code:

Please consider switching to just about anything else, so you do not clutter up the root of the user's external storage with random directories. Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()` (both on `Context`), or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDir()` instead.

> Depending on the Android version this will be a different dir. e.g. /mnt/sdcard/dir_name, /storage/sdcard0/dir_name

This will not be a problem, so long as you are not trying to save these absolute paths somewhere (e.g., in a database).

> Is there a guarantee that the old location will exist as a symlink to the new location?

No. This is why the documentation recommends that you do not persist absolute paths to locations on external storage.

Comment: thx. I know that there is no guarantee to store on SD card. `getExternalFileDir` is not persistent when uninstall. `cachDir` also not appropriate. I'm not storing the abs path anywhere (see question). The question is: Will the code I'm using still find my files, after a OS update that changes the location of `getExternalStorageDirectory()`?